# Selecting a set of numbers from a list which add up to a given value

Tags: python, list, combinations

How can I choose some numbers from a given list so that their sum is a certain given number?

Example:

```
wanted_num = 10
my_list = [1, 3, 11, 123, 5, 4]

=> [1, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to find 2 numbers which sum to the desired number, or the smallest size set that sums to it? What happens if there are multiple sets which sum to the desired number?

Comment: it could be multiple numbers that make up the sum. In this case it is only 2

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way to do it:

```
def find_combinations(list, sum):
    if not list:
        if sum == 0:
            return [[]]
        return []
    return find_combinations(list[1:], sum) + \
        [[list[0]] + tail for tail in
         find_combinations(list[1:], sum - list[0])]
```

For your example, this would return:

```
>>> print find_combinations([1, 3, 11, 123, 5, 4], 10)
[[1, 5, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic version that checks for more than just pairs (basically, any n-tuples that add up to the required target)

```
def findSum(target, L, sofar=None):
    if sofar is None:
        sofar = []
    if not target:
        print(sofar)
        return
    if target < 0:
        return
    for i,num in enumerate(L):
        findSum(target-num, L[:i]+L[i+1:], sofar+[num])
```

Output:

```
In [34]: findSum(10, [1,3,11,123,5,7])
[3, 7]
[7, 3]
```

Note that it doesn't exclude similar sets

Answer (score -2):

The solution below should work:

```
wanted_num = 10
my_list = [1, 3, 11, 123, 5, 7]
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    for j in range(0, len(my_list)):
        if i + j == wanted_num:
            answer = [i, j]
            break

print(answer)
```

This solution assumes there's only two numbers that add up to `wanted_num`.
Hope it helps.