# trying add two numbers ,by reading them from list and print their index no. from their actual list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
,in each input would have  not use the same element twice.

```
class solution():
    def __init__(self,array_num,target_num):
        self.array_num=array_num
        self.target_num=target_num
    
        for  t in self.array_num:
            for  b in self.array_num:
                e=t+b
                w=self.array_num.index(t),self.array_num.index(b)
                y=list(w)
                if e==self.target_num:
                    
                    if y==[0,0]:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(y)

p=[3,3]
so=solution(p,6)
```

**output**

```
[] or nothing
```

**expected output**

```
[0,1]
```

Comment: I don't get any output, not even `[]`.

Comment: i also don't get any output in notebook but when i paste this code in leet code editor i get [] as  output

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083819/selecting-a-set-of-numbers-from-a-list-which-add-up-to-a-given-value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are asking the list to give you the index if a number like this:

```
self.array_num.index(t)
```

This will always give you the first occurrence, which is 0 here, although the loop is actually at the second position with index 1.

To avoid that, reverse the logic: create the loop for the index (use `len()` and `range()`), then get the number at that position.

As this question sounds like homework or school assignment, I'll not post a full solution. It should be possible to solve the problem now.

More hints to make your teacher happy:

- `[0, 0]` is not the only solution that results in 6. You want to exclude other invalid combinations as well. Pro tip: there's a nice solution that doesn't require any check *and* will run faster. It's easy to find once you switched the logic.
- Currently you do all work in the constructor of the object. Maybe you want  a method that does the actual calculation.
- Your variable names are not self-explaining. Don't use so many single letter variables.